# There is some sequence $x_n$ in $C[a,b]$ such that $\|x_n\| =1$ but $x_n(t)$ tends to $0$ for all t $\in [a,b] $.

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $\| \|$ be a norm on $C[a,b]$. Then there is some sequence $x_n$ in $C[a,b]$ such that $\|x_n\| =1$ but $x_n(t)$  tends to $0$ for all t $\in [a,b] $.

Answer (score 2):

Example
$$
x_n(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
0 & \text{if} & t\in \big[0,\frac{1}{n}\big], \\
nt-1 & \text{if} & t\in \big[\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n}\big], \\
3-nt & \text{if} & t\in \big[\frac{2}{n},\frac{3}{n}\big], \\
0 & \text{if} & t\in \big[\frac{3}{n},1\big].
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Then $x_n$ continuous,  $0\le x_n(t)\le 1$ and $x_n\big(\frac{2}{n}\big)=1$.

Comment: But I need $\| x_n \| =1$. Here $\| \|$ is not the supremum norm. This is any given norm on $C[a,b].$

Comment: @Anu Essentially the same example works for any norm. Let $x_n$ be as above. Choose $c_n>0$ so $||y_n||=1$ if $y_n=c_nx_n$. Then $y_n(t)\to0$ for every $t$.

Comment: Thank you sir:)